# response timeout on http request

Tags: node.js, httprequest, electron, httpresponse

I am making an application with electron.js and I have reached a point where I need to make an http request to call a php. Response time at the beginning was low and the application failed before receiving data. Then I put a timeOut to the HTTP path so that the wait time for the server response increased. The problem esque is as if the timeOut was not, does not wait for the indicated one.

Do you know any way to solve this problem?

```
var http = require('http');
    var options = {
      timeout: 50000,
      host: localStorage.getItem('server'),
      port: localStorage.getItem('port'),
      path: localStorage.getItem('directori') + '?nosession=1&call=ciberFiSessio&numSerie='+ localStorage.getItem("pc")
    };
http.get(options, function(res) {
      alert("hola");
      if (res.statusCode  == 200){
        //reinicia();

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          str = chunk;
          alert(str);

          var myJSON = JSON.parse(str);
          //alert(myJSON.fi);

          if(parseInt(myJSON.fi)==0){
            alert("Hi ha hagut un problema!");
          }else{
            reinicia();
          }

        });

      }else{
        alert("El lloc ha caigut!");
        alert(res.statusCode);
      }
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      alert("Hi ha un error: " + e.message);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `node-fetch` library, which support more complex options, and also works with Promises, which is modern approach for design async applications.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Supported options (from documentation, `timeout` included)

```
{
    method: 'GET'
    , headers: {}        // request header. format {a:'1'} or {b:['1','2','3']}
    , redirect: 'follow' // set to `manual` to extract redirect headers, `error` to reject redirect
    , follow: 20         // maximum redirect count. 0 to not follow redirect
    , timeout: 0         // req/res timeout in ms, it resets on redirect. 0 to disable (OS limit applies)
    , compress: true     // support gzip/deflate content encoding. false to disable
    , size: 0            // maximum response body size in bytes. 0 to disable
    , body: empty        // request body. can be a string, buffer, readable stream
    , agent: null        // http.Agent instance, allows custom proxy, certificate etc.
}
```